# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in H:\wamp\www\custom\wp-includes\class-wp-http-curl.php

Tags: theme-development, fatal-error, unit-tests

I imported the [Theme Unit Test](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test) xml file with the wordpress importer. But all of the data is imported as pages. I am following an online tutorial to build a wordpress theme development and I believe the data should be imported as posts.

When I proceed with the import. I can choose to import authors or to assign a existing author and I can choose to import/download attachments (which I did).

I get a fatal error

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in H:\wamp\www\custom\wp-includes\class-wp-http-curl.php
```

I get a bunch of pages and media but no posts.

Although I am also increase those values:

max_execution_time = 5000

max_input_time = 5000

memory_limit = 1000M

How should I fix this so I can import all the content?

Comment: `max_execution_time = 5000` is 83 minutes.  And you still get a time exceeded error?  Can you do an import using the 2015 theme?

Comment: No I am using 2016 theme.

Comment: Try 2015 without plugins.  If it still doesn't work you might have a server configuration issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. How to configure this.

Comment: I don't know, every system is different.

Comment: It seems to me that your are trying to download attachements from a non-correct/non-accessible remote location, or you have a connection issue, which is causing the max. excution time be triggered in the HTTP request made to download the attachments.

Answer (score 8):

I get that answer.

I go to this file: `wp-includes/deprecated.php` and find this line in (deprecated) `wp_get_http()` function:

```
@set_time_limit ( 60 );
```

just comment out this line and it works fine.

Because wordpress hard coded that 60 seconds limit, this hard coded setting was over-ridding my `php.ini` settings. so I comment out that line, my `php.ini` settings will start working again.

Comment: This solution worked only within so many online solutions for me. Thank you very much for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just to the point..
In wp-config.php paste this code-line

set_time_limit(180);

set your recommend execution time (PHP Time Limit) and done!..

Important: Paste before

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

That's all.

Never forget this, Silence is golden :))